# Running length of the movie in a human readable format

Tags: code-golf, conversion

Whenever I search for the running length of a movie in IMDb, it is displayed in minutes. Immediately I would try to convert it into hour(s) and minute(s). It would be better if we could automate this.

Input:

```
150 min
```

Output:

```
2 hours 30 minutes
```

Input:

```
90 min
```

Output:

```
1 hour 30 minutes
```

Input:

```
61 min
```

Output:

```
1 hour 1 minute
```

Input:

```
60 min
```

Output:

```
1 hour 0 minute or 1 hour 0 minutes
```

**Following are the conditions:**

1. Input and Output should be in this exact format.
2. Input minutes will between 0 and 240.
3. Your answer can accept command line arguments or read input from the
   user or a function.
4. Output should not be enclosed within quotes.
5. Output must be printed, not returned.

**Leaderboard:**

```js
    var QUESTION_ID=65106,OVERRIDE_USER=16196;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/65106/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
    body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}#answer-list{padding-right: 100px}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

## Result:

Its a tie between CJam and Pyth. Accepting CJam's answer as it was submitted before Pyth's 35 bytes code. However, please continue encouraging new submissions.

Comment: Must the answer be a complete program?

Comment: @quintopia According to [site rules](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/3808), no. You can use a function if you want to.

Comment: Technically, I (and I bet other humans) can read "150 minutes".

Comment: Why restrict to >59 minutes?  Also, I prefer 61 minutes to 1 hour 1 minute and really would hate seeing 1 hour 0 minutes

Comment: case sensitivity?

Comment: @markshancock You're right even I kept thinking about that. Check the updated question.

Comment: You changed the input range to be 0-240 but haven't included any test cases less than 60. I recommend sticking with the original range given that 28 answers have already been posted.

Comment: It appears you also changed the acceptable output for whole hours. Unless a challenge has blaring issues that *need* to be fixed, please do not make changes to a challenge that invalidate existing answers.

Comment: @markshancock Please don't suggest edits that break existing answers, re: x hours 0 minutes

Comment: @Sherlock, nothing wrong with expressing an opinion

Comment: I have reverted it back so existing answers won't get affected. I just felt all answers would be consistent i.e. one answer outputs `1 hour 0 minute` and the other one like `1 hour 0 minutes`.

Comment: @PyRulez Just to reduce additional effort :)

Comment: @sysreq It should be in the exact format as given in the test cases. So only lowercase letters.

Comment: @markshancock Ah yes. That's fair. Well, express away but also note if implementing that opinion would break existing answers. Thank you

Comment: @Sherlock, Wished my customers always knew exactly what they wanted and so I never had to change my code ... well, maybe not, they keep coming back.  ;)

Comment: @Sherlock, btw, if your code met the initial requirement. I'm sure people would understand you not making mods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## CJam, <s>39</s> 35 bytes

```
ri60md]"hour minute"S/.{1$1>'s*+}S*
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri60md%5D%22hour%20minute%22S%2F.%7B1%241%3E's*%2B%7DS*&input=90%20min)

Latest version includes improvements suggested by @MartinBüttner, particularly using the element-wise vector operator instead of transposing the two lists.

Explanation:

```
ri    Get input and convert to integer.
60md  Split into hours and minutes by calculating moddiv of input.
]     Wrap hours and minutes in a list.
"hour minute"
      String with units.
S/    Split it at spaces, giving ["hour" "minute"]
.{    Apply block element-wise to pair of vectors.
  1$    Copy number to top.
  1>    Check for greater than 1.
  's    Push 's.
  *     Multiply with comparison result, giving 's if greater 1, nothing otherwise.
  +     Concatenate optional 's with rest of string.
}     End block applied to both parts.
S*    Join with spaces.
```

Comment: 35: `ri60md]r"utehour"+6/W%.{1$1>'s*+}S*` (Looks like this gives you a pretty solid lead on this challenge :))

Comment: @MartinBüttner `r"utehour"+6/W%` is actually the same length as `"hour minute"S/`, so that part ends up not helping. I think I had seen `.` used with a block before, but I had forgotten again that it was supported.

Comment: Ah, right, I had first posted a 36-byte version where it actually helped (but then deleted the comment and replaced it by the 35-byte version where it doesn't matter any more).

Answer (score 19):

## Python 3, <s>50</s> <s>67</s> <s>119</s> <s>116</s> <s>112</s> <s>111</s> <s>104</s> 94 bytes

<s>I'm not fond of going back to `%`-style string formatting, but it saves 6 bytes on `.format`.</s>

**Edit:** Forgot to parse input.

**Edit:** Forgot to handle plurals.

<s>**Edit:** Yay lambdas!</s>

**Edit:** Added ungolfing

**Edit:** Darn it. Lambdas didn't help.

**Edit:** Since the minutes have maximum three digits, and `int()` doesn't mind spaces in the string, I can save a few bytes by using `input()[:3]`.

```python
i,j=divmod(int(input()[:3]),60);print(str(i),"hour"+("s"[:i!=1]),str(j),"minute"+("s"[:i!=1]))
```

Ungolfed:

```python
string = input()[:3]
hours, minutes = divmod(int(string), 60)
a = string(div)
b = "hour" + ("s" if hours == 1 else "")
c = string(mod)
d = "minute" + ("s" if minutes == 1 else "")
print(a, b, c, d)
```

Comment: Ah! *Increasing* bytecount! +1 for not giving up ;-)

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript, 78 bytes

```js
n=>(h=(n=parseInt(n))/60|0)+` hour${h-1?"s":""} ${m=n%60} minute`+(m-1?"s":"")
```

```html
<!--                               Try the test suite below!                              --><strong id="bytecount" style="display:inline; font-size:32px; font-family:Helvetica"></strong><strong id="bytediff" style="display:inline; margin-left:10px; font-size:32px; font-family:Helvetica; color:lightgray"></strong><br><br><pre style="margin:0">Code:</pre><textarea id="textbox" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px"></textarea><br><pre style="margin:0">Input:</pre><textarea id="inputbox" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px"></textarea><br><button id="testbtn">Test!</button><button id="resetbtn">Reset</button><br><p><strong id="origheader" style="font-family:Helvetica; display:none">Original Code Output:</strong><p><div id="origoutput" style="margin-left:15px"></div><p><strong id="newheader" style="font-family:Helvetica; display:none">New Code Output:</strong><p><div id="newoutput" style="margin-left:15px"></div><script type="text/javascript" id="golfsnippet">var bytecount=document.getElementById("bytecount");var bytediff=document.getElementById("bytediff");var textbox=document.getElementById("textbox");var inputbox=document.getElementById("inputbox");var testbtn=document.getElementById("testbtn");var resetbtn=document.getElementById("resetbtn");var origheader=document.getElementById("origheader");var newheader=document.getElementById("newheader");var origoutput=document.getElementById("origoutput");var newoutput=document.getElementById("newoutput");textbox.style.width=inputbox.style.width=window.innerWidth-50+"px";var _originalCode=null;function getOriginalCode(){if(_originalCode!=null)return _originalCode;var allScripts=document.getElementsByTagName("script");for(var i=0;i<allScripts.length;i++){var script=allScripts[i];if(script.id!="golfsnippet"){originalCode=script.textContent.trim();return originalCode}}}function getNewCode(){return textbox.value.trim()}function getInput(){try{var inputText=inputbox.value.trim();var input=eval("["+inputText+"]");return input}catch(e){return null}}function setTextbox(s){textbox.value=s;onTextboxChange()}function setOutput(output,s){output.innerHTML=s}function addOutput(output,data){output.innerHTML+='<pre style="background-color:'+(data.type=="err"?"lightcoral":"lightgray")+'">'+escape(data.content)+"</pre>"}function getByteCount(s){return(new Blob([s],{encoding:"UTF-8",type:"text/plain;charset=UTF-8"})).size}function onTextboxChange(){var newLength=getByteCount(getNewCode());var oldLength=getByteCount(getOriginalCode());bytecount.innerHTML=newLength+" bytes";var diff=newLength-oldLength;if(diff>0){bytediff.innerHTML="(+"+diff+")";bytediff.style.color="lightcoral"}else if(diff<0){bytediff.innerHTML="("+diff+")";bytediff.style.color="lightgreen"}else{bytediff.innerHTML="("+diff+")";bytediff.style.color="lightgray"}}function onTestBtn(evt){origheader.style.display="inline";newheader.style.display="inline";setOutput(newoutput,"");setOutput(origoutput,"");var input=getInput();if(input===null){addOutput(origoutput,{type:"err",content:"Input is malformed. Using no input."});addOutput(newoutput,{type:"err",content:"Input is malformed. Using no input."});input=[]}doInterpret(getNewCode(),input,function(data){addOutput(newoutput,data)});doInterpret(getOriginalCode(),input,function(data){addOutput(origoutput,data)});evt.stopPropagation();return false}function onResetBtn(evt){setTextbox(getOriginalCode());origheader.style.display="none";newheader.style.display="none";setOutput(origoutput,"");setOutput(newoutput,"")}function escape(s){return s.toString().replace(/&/g,"&amp;").replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;")}window.alert=function(){};window.prompt=function(){};function doInterpret(code,input,cb){var workerCode=interpret.toString()+";function stdout(s){ self.postMessage( {'type': 'out', 'content': s} ); }"+" function stderr(s){ self.postMessage( {'type': 'err', 'content': s} ); }"+" function kill(){ self.close(); }"+" self.addEventListener('message', function(msg){ interpret(msg.data.code, msg.data.input); });";var interpreter=new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([workerCode])));interpreter.addEventListener("message",function(msg){cb(msg.data)});interpreter.postMessage({"code":code,"input":input});setTimeout(function(){interpreter.terminate()},1E4)}setTimeout(function(){getOriginalCode();textbox.addEventListener("input",onTextboxChange);testbtn.addEventListener("click",onTestBtn);resetbtn.addEventListener("click",onResetBtn);setTextbox(getOriginalCode())},100);function interpret(code,input){window={};alert=function(s){stdout(s)};window.alert=alert;console.log=alert;prompt=function(s){if(input.length<1)stderr("not enough input");else{var nextInput=input[0];input=input.slice(1);return nextInput.toString()}};window.prompt=prompt;(function(){try{var evalResult=eval(code);if(typeof evalResult=="function"){var callResult=evalResult.apply(this,input);if(typeof callResult!="undefined")stdout(callResult)}}catch(e){stderr(e.message)}})()};</script>
```

For the test suite, enter input like `"61 min"` into the input box.

#### Explanation

```
n=>                 //Define anonymous function w/ parameter n
(h=                 //start building the string to return with h, the # of hours
(n=parseInt(n))     //parse input for n
/60|0)+             //set h to floor(n / 60)
` hour              //add ' hour' to the string to return
${h-1?"s":""}       //add 's' to the string to return if h != 1, else add ''
                    //<--(a single space) add ' ' to the string to return
${m=n%60}           //set m, the # of miuntes, to n % 60, and add it to the string to return
 minute`+           //add ' minute' to the string to return
(m-1?"s":"")        //add 's' to the string to return if m != 1, else add ''
                    //implicitly return
```

Comment: Good one. Suggestion: reduce `parseInt(n)` to `+n`.

Comment: @nicael That doesn't work, I tried. :( It returns `NaN`. You can try to edit the code by using the test snippet I've provided in the answer if you want to see for yourself.

Comment: Ah, I got it: with `parseInt()`, you're not only parsing int but also removing 'min' from the string (forgot it also does the latter). Yeah, in this case my suggestion is invalid.

Comment: Input will not be just an integer. It fails when i provide input as `150 min`.

Comment: @VasuAdari It's working for me, outputs `2 hours 30 minutes`. May I ask how you tested it?

Comment: Sorry i entered wrongly :P. It works :)

Comment: Doesn't work... "Input is malformed. Using no input."

Comment: @ev3commander When using the test snippet, wrap the input in quotes so that it is recognized as a string. e.g. `"61 min"` or `'61 min'`

Comment: @ev3commander JavaScript ;)

Comment: +1 For JavaScript. Now you just have to make it a [bookmarlet](http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/) ;)

Comment: You forgot to specify that this is ES6

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <strike>39</strike> 38 bytes

```
jd.iJ.Dv-zG60+Vc"hour minute")m*\s>d1J
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), <s>57</s> <s>54</s> 52 bytes

Oh, wow, I don't even have integers in my language. o-o

```
VVa6*Dv/D1M-D1m'ruoh 'Z' 'OVvM1m'etunim 'Z
N1-(['s']
```

```
VV                                      Capture the input as a final global 
                                        variable, and push it again.
  a6*Dv/1M-                             Get floor(input/60), capturing 60 as a 
                                        temp variable in the process.
           DN                           Duplicate and output it as a number.
             1-(['s']                   If it is only one, push 's'.

            'ruoh '                     Push ' hour'
                   Z                    Output everything.
                    ' 'O                Output a space.
V                                       Push the input.
 v                                      Get the temp variable (60).
  M                                     Modulo.
            N                           Output as a number.
             1-(['s']                   If it is only one, push 's'.

             'ruoh '                    Push ' hour'
                    Z                   Output everything.
```

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=VlZhNipEdi9EMU0tMW0ncnVvaCAnWicgJ09Wdk0xbSdldHVuaW0gJ1oKRE4xLShbJ3MnXQ&input=&args=MjQx&debug=on)

Answer (score 4):

### Pyth, 46 bytes

```
jKdm++J.v+++hd:z03K60K+td*\s>J1c"/hour %minute
```

Takes input as `x min` and outputs `x hours y minutes`

Try it [Here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jKdm%2B%2BJ.v%2B%2B%2Bhd%3Az03K60K%2Btd*%5Cs%3EJ1c%22%2Fhour+%25minute&input=162+min&debug=1)

Explanation:

```
   m~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~c"/hour %minute - map(func, "/hour %minute".split(" "))
            hd                                 - Get the first character of the string (/ or %)
              :z03                             - Get the first 3 characters of input
         +++      K60                          - Join them together and add a space and 60 to the end
      J.v                                      - Evaluate it and set result to J
                       td                      - Get all the characters of the string but the first (hour, minute)
                      +  *\s>J1                - If the result of the evaluated expression is less than 1, add an 's' character to the string
    ++               K                         - Join the results seperated with a space
jKd                                            - Join the 2 halves together with a space
```

Answer (score 4):

## K5, <s>55</s> 51 bytes

```
" "/(" hour";" minute"){y,x,("s";"")1=.y}'$25 60\.*" "\
```

This is more general than it strictly has to be; might still golf it down further.

In action:

```
  f: " "/(" hour";" minute"){y,x,("s";"")1=.y}'$25 60\.*" "\;

  f'("61 min";"120 min";"150 min")
("1 hour 1 minute"
 "2 hours 0 minutes"
 "2 hours 30 minutes")
```

### Edit:

This program went through several very different iterations in the course of development, and I thought that it might be more illuminating to show some of the intermediate steps.

Here was my first stab at the problem, before the pluralization requirement was introduced. There is clear repetition here:

```
{($_x%60)," hours ",($_60!x)," minutes"}@.*" "\
```

I realized that the general way to handle casting out of places was K5's "decode" form. To slot values into place in the string I used the "dot-apply" primitive, which applies an argument list to a function and unpacks the list into individual parameters:

```
{x," hours ",y," minutes"}.$25 60\.*" "\
```

Not much redundancy left here. When pluralization was added, I decomposed that leading anonymous function into a transformation I could apply to each number, like this:

```
{x,y,("s";"")1=.x}
```

Join `x`, `y`, and either `s` or nothing, depending on whether `x` is equal to "1". Ultimately it worked better to reverse the order of the arguments to this function.

### Edit 2:

```
" "/(" hour";" minute"){y,x,("s";"")1=.y}'$25 60\.*" "\
" "/(" hour";" minute"){y,x,(~1=.y)#"s"}'$5 60\.-4_
```

Several small improvements here. A better way of selecting an "s" or an empty string, a shorter constant for "decode" which reflects the limited range of input, and a simpler way of discarding "min".

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>100</s> <s>94</s> <s>89</s> 81  bytes

```
t=>(h=0|(t=parseInt(t))/60)+' hour'+(h>1?'s ':' ')+t%60+' minute'+(t%60>1?'s':'')
```

De-golfed demo (converted to ES5, as not all the browsers support ES6 yet)

```js
function s(t) {
  return (h = 0 | (t = parseInt(t)) / 60) + ' hour' + (h > 1 ? 's ' : ' ') + t % 60 + ' minute' + (t % 60 > 1 ? 's' : '');
}

alert(s(prompt()))
```

Comment: You could wrap `t=parseInt(t)` and parenthesis, and then put that where ever you first use `t` so: `(h=0|(t=parseInt(t))/60)`. This way, you can remove the return and the `{}`

Comment: @Downgoat I've already tried but it didn't work for some reason. Will try again.

Comment: @Downgoat Apparently I've made a mistake previously, now it works properly. Thanks :)

Comment: USE TEMPLATE STRINGS. ${}!!!

Answer (score 3):

### [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), <s>80</s> 73 bytes

80 byte original

```perl6
{my$h=$_ div 60;my$m=$_%60;"$h hour{'s'x?($h-1)}"~" $m minute{'s'x?($m-1)}"x?$m}
```

Usage:

```perl6
.say for (150,90,61,60).map:
  {my$h=$_ div 60;my$m=$_%60;"$h hour{'s'x?($h-1)}"~" $m minute{'s'x?($m-1)}"x?$m}
```

```
2 hours 30 minutes
1 hour 30 minutes
1 hour 1 minute
1 hour
```

Due to a change in the question I can remove `x?$m` from the end of the function, which allows me to reduce it by 3 more bytes.

```perl6
{my$h=$_ div 60;my$m=$_%60;"$h hour{'s'x?($h-1)} $m minute{'s'x?($m-1)}"}
```

```
2 hours 30 minutes
1 hour 30 minutes
1 hour 1 minute
1 hour 0 minutes
```

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 127 bytes

```
var i=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine().Split(' ')[0]);Console.Write(i/60+" hour"+(i/60>1?"s ":" ")+i%60+" minute"+(i%60>1?"s":""));
```

This can be put in a file and run via the [C# interactive shell](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/repl/) that comes with Mono, using the default configuration.

[This is my first attempt at code golf. I hope that my contribution is not violating any rules.]

Answer (score 3):

## C, 89 bytes

```
main(n){scanf("%d",&n);printf("%d hour%s %d minute%s",n/60,"s"+119/n,n%60,"s"+(n%60<2));}
```

Comment: Please specify environment, [on gcc `44 min` => `0 hour%d hour%s %d minute%s 44 minutes`](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI0@zujg5MS9NQ0k1RUlHLU/TuqAoM68EzFfIyC8tUi1WALJyM/NKS1JVi5V08vTNDHSUipW0DQ0t9fN08lShXA0Qy8ZIU9O69v9/ExOQDgA)

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 75 bytes

```
a,b=gets.to_i.divmod 60;$><<"#{a} hour#{a>1??s:''} #{b} minute#{b>1??s:''}"
```

Comment: Sometimes even an empty string is too long. `''` → `p`.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, <s>111 108</s> 106 bytes

```
i=sscanf(input(''),'%d');h=fix(i/60);m=i-h*60;fprintf('%d hour%c %d minute%c\n',h,'s'*(h~=1),m,'s'*(m~=1))
```

This also works with **Octave**, and can be tried [here](http://octave-online.net/?s=QHPazBNGkfyhbhbdFrYAnJeGZmDvKMKYapOgHyikJRbmUTQP). The link is to a workspace already containing the code in a file named `runningLength.m`. So to test it out simply enter `runningLength` at the prompt, then enter the input string, e.g. `'123 mins'` and it will display the output.

Takes the input as a string, e.g. `'123 mins'`, converts it to a number (which implicitly ignores the `mins` bit).

```
i=sscanf(input(''),'%d');
```

Minutes and hours are then calculated

```
h=fix(i/60);m=i-h*60;
```

Then displays the output string

```
fprintf('%d hour%c %d minute%c',h,'s'*(h~=1),m,'s'*(m~=1));
```

The 's' bit of the output is calculated and handled correctly - an 's' is added whenever the number is not 1.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>117</s> 109 bytes

```
f x|(d,m)<-divMod(read$take 3 x)60=putStr$u[d#"hour",m#"minute"];u=unwords;1#q=u["1",q];p#q=u[show p,q++"s"]
```

Less golfed version:

```
f :: String -> IO ()
f x = putStr (unwords [(n`div`60)#"hour",(n`mod`60)#"minute"])
  where
  n :: Int
  n = take 3 (read x)

  (#) :: Int -> String -> String
  1#q = unwords ["1",q]
  p#q = unwords [show p,q++"s"]
```

`f` is  a function which takes the first 3 characters of its input and converts them to an integer.
`p#q` is a function which pluralises `q` if `p` is not equal to 1. In order to return the result without surrounding quotes, I used `putStr` to print the result to STDOUT.

Thanks to nimi for the help!

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>79</s> 77 bytes

```
m=int(raw_input()[:3])
print m/60,"hours"[:4+m/120],m%60,"minutes"[:6+m/2%30]
```

The first 3 characters of the input are simply parsed as an integer. This only works because the third character in a 2 digit input is a space, which `int` will ignore during conversion.

Comment: I think you can just do `"hour"+m/120*"s"` and likewise for minutes.

Comment: It'll fail for `m=240`, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 112 bytes

**Edit**: Fixed a scoping error and then addressed the quotation output issue.

```
g=function(x){h=floor(x/60);m=x%%60;cat(paste(h,ifelse(h==1,"hour","hours"),m,ifelse(m==1,"minute","minutes")))}
```

#### Test cases

```
> g(150)
2 hours 30 minutes
> g(90)
1 hour 30 minutes
> g(61)
1 hour 1 minute
> g(60)
1 hour 0 minutes
```

I tried to save space by trying to find a way to just add or subtract "s" as necessary but I had to mess with the `sep =` argument in the `paste()` function and it didn't really seem like it was going to save me very much space. Any suggestions?

#### Ungolfed

```
g=function(x){
    h=floor(x/60);
    m=x%%60;
    cat(paste(h,
              ifelse(h==1,"hour","hours"),
              m,
              ifelse(m==1,"minute","minutes")))
}
```

Rounding down with input/60 or input%%60 (mod) gives the hours and minutes respectively. Chain them together with an `ifelse()` statement that specifies whether or not the units are hour(s) or minute(s).

Comment: Output should not be enclosed within quotes.

Comment: @Vasu Adari Fixed it using the `cat()` function.

Comment: You can save bytes by handling plural with just  `s`  and by changing your conditions.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <del>107</del> 101 bytes

```
g=putStr.f.read.take 3;s!1='1':s;s!n=show n++s++"s";f x|(a,b)<-divMod x 60=" hour"!a++' ':" minute"!b
```

Ungolfed:

```
g :: String -> String
g = putStr . f . read . take 3 
  where
    (!) :: String -> Int -> String
    s!1 = '1':s
    s!n = show n++s++"s"

    f :: Int -> String;
    f x
      | (a,b) <- divMod x 60 = " hour"!a ++ ' ':(" minute"!b)
```

`s!n` prepends `n` to `s`, adding a `'s'` to the end if `n /= 1`.

`f x` does the formatting after using `divMod`.

Since we can assume a max input of `240`, `take 3` is sufficient to take only the number.

(Had to try really hard to beat @Craig Roy's score...)

Answer (score 2):

## LabVIEW, 50 Bytes

This is counted according to [my suggestion on Meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7589/39490).

The code is pretty straight forward, take number from input Modulo by 60 and add an s for minutes != 1. Other side of case just puts the string through.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 135 bytes

```
var a=(i:String)=>{var (v,b)=(i.split(" ")(0).toInt,(i:Int)=>if(i<2)""else"s");printf(v/60+" hour"+b(v/60)+" "+v%60+" minute"+b(v%60))}
```

**Usage:**

```
a("120 min")
2 hours 0 minute
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 96 bytes

```
i=int(raw_input().split()[0])
print"%d hour%s %d minute%s"%(i/60,"s"*(i>120),i%60,"s"*(i%60!=1))
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to correctly handle plurals.

Comment: @Doorknob This is what happens when the rules get changed after answers are posted :)

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 152 bytes

Sorry, fixed the code so it handles the input/output the way the insturctions say.

```
 def t(p):
  import math
  print(str(math.floor(p/60))+" hour" + ("s " if math.floor(p/60>1) else " ") +str(p%60)+" minute" + ("s " if p%60>1 else ""))
```

Edit:
 <s>Why is the still -1 with the edited code? It works exactly how the OP asks.</s>

Comment: You don't need the comma or the period. c:

Comment: Also, I think that round also has a chance of going up, making `239` be 4 hours and 59 minutes.

Comment: @Mego yeah I noticed that. I will fix this as soon as possible. On mobile right now

Comment: `from math import*` will save you bytes

Comment: Do you really need those spaces in between?

Comment: @VasuAdari no I don't. I thought I fixed that but it looks like the edit never saved. Thanks.

Comment: You still have some space before and after `+`. Is that really needed?

Comment: @VasuAdari yeah I know thanks. Sorry, when I went back and did it I was in a rush. Honestly, don't have much time for golfing during weekdays, on the weekend il go back and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>97</s> <s>100</s> <s>99</s> 88 bytes

**Edit:** Fixing output.

**Edit:** Removing braces from `divmod`.

**Edit:** Yay string interpolation! Thanks to [Vasu Adari](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16196/vasu-adari). Also, better ungolfing.

```
i,j=gets.split[0].to_i.divmod 60;puts"#{i} hour#{i==1?"":"s"} #{j} minute#{j==1?"":"s"}"
```

Ungolfed:

```
input = gets                            Input
number = input.split[0].to_i            Get number, convert to int
hours, minutes = number.divmod 60       hours == s / 60, minutes == s % 60
result = hours.to_s+" hour"             Start with the hours
result += {hours == 1 ? "" : "s"}       Put in the first "s" if plural
result += minutes.to_s+" minute"        Add the minutes
result += {minutes == 1 ? "" : "s"}     Put in the second "s" if plural
puts result                             Output
```

Comment: o/p should not be enclosed within quotes.

Comment: @VasuAdari Fixed

Comment: You can lose the braces for `divmod` method. Also by using string interpolation you can save few bytes.

Comment: @VasuAdari I am aware of that string iterpolation is a thing, but I'm not sure what it is or how it works. Thanks for the help

Comment: @VasuAdari Oop, wait. Google has taught me what I need to know. Let me get editing.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 61 bytes

```
Print@ToString[Quantity@#~UnitConvert~MixedRadix["h","min"]]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## Go, 177 Bytes

(It includes only the function and the import  statements)

```
import("fmt";c"strconv";t"strings")
func f(s string){p,_:=c.Atoi(t.Split(s," ")[0]);t:=fmt.Printf;h:=p/60;m:=p%60;t("%d Hour",h);if h>1{t("s")};t(" %d Minute",m);if m>1{t("s")}}
```

Pretty solution -

```
func f(s string) {
    p, _ := c.Atoi(t.Split(s, " ")[0])
    t := fmt.Printf
    h := p / 60;m := p % 60
    t("%d Hour", h)
    if h > 1 {
        t("s")
    }
    t(" %d Minute", m)
    if m > 1 {
        t("s")
    }
}
```

Testing it -

```
func main() {
    ip_list := []string{
        "120 min",
        "150 min",
        "60 min",
    }

    for _, ip_val := range ip_list {
        f(ip_val)
        fmt.Println("")
    }
}

/* OUTPUT
2 Hours 0 Minute
2 Hours 30 Minutes
1 Hour 0 Minute
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 77 bytes

```
ε" min",Æ≈;:60:@\@:60:@%'sε(;)1≥I"%d hour"+(#@%'sε(;)1≥I"%d minute"+(#@%@k' j
```

Seriously is *seriously* not good at string manipulation. [Try it online with full explanation](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=ee22206d696e222c92f73b3a36303a405c403a36303a40252773ee283b2931f24922256420686f7572222b282340252773ee283b2931f249222564206d696e757465222b28234025406b27206a) (you will need to manually enter the input like `"210 mins"` because permalinks don't like quotes).

Quick and dirty explanation:

```
ε" min",Æ≈            get input, replace " min" with the empty string, convert to int
;:60:@\@:60:@%        calculate divmod
'sε(;)1≥I"%d hour"+   push "%d hour" or "%d hours", depending on whether pluralization is needed
(#@%                  format "%d hour(s)" with the # of hours calculated earlier
'sε(;)1≥I"%d minute"+ same as above, but with minutes
(#@%                  same as above, but with minutes
@k' j                 swap the order and join with a space to get "X hour(s) X minute(s)"
```

Comment: Your link does not work

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>74</s> <s>73</s> 71 bytes

```
->i{puts"#{i=i.to_i;h=i/60} hour#{h>1??s:''} #{m=i%60} minute#{m>1??s:''}"}
```

**73 bytes**

```
->i{puts"#{h,m=i.to_i.divmod 60;h} hour#{h>1??s:''} #{m} minute#{m>1??s:''}"}
```

**74 bytes:**

```
->i{h,m=i.to_i.divmod 60;puts "#{h} hour#{h>1??s:''} #{m} minute#{m>1??s:''}"}
```

**Usage:**

```
->i{puts"#{i=i.to_i;h=i/60} hour#{h>1??s:''} #{m=i%60} minute#{m>1??s:''}"}[61]

1 hour 1 minute
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```
$m=($i=$argv[1])%60;echo$h=$i/60|0," hour","s"[$h<2]," $m minute","s"[$m<2];
```

horible, horible, horible!
PHP only issues a couple of `Notice`s for `"s"[$h<2]`

To run: `php -r 'CODE' '150 minutes'`
and of course turn error reporting off/away from stdout!

Edit: -1byte assign in assign (credit: insertusernamehere)

It's so ugly I must give a run helper for linux users:

```
php -c /usr/share/php5/php.ini-production.cli -r 'CODE' '61 min'
```

Comment: **1 byte** less: `$m=($i=$argv[1])%60;echo$h=$i/60|0," hour","s"[$h<2]," $m minute","s"[$m<2];`.

Comment: @insertusernamehere nice, thanks! crazy

Comment: You're welcome. Even **4 bytes** lesser (was too tired to notice yesterday): `$m=($i=$argv[1])%60;echo$h=$i/60|0," hour",s[$h<2]," $m minute",s[$m<2];`.

Comment: @insertusernamehere that's a really nasty old one, but can't believe it works for php 5.6-7 and not for 5.3-5.5

Comment: I've tested it with PHP 5.6.10 (OS X) and it works here. :)

Answer (score 1):

### [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com), <s>174</s> <s>170</s> 160 bytes

```
x::Send,% !i?"x" i:=SubStr(clipboard,1,(Clipboard~="\s")):"{Backspace "StrLen(i)"}" i//60 " Hour"(i//60!=1?"s ":" ")Mod(i,60)" Minute"(Mod(i,60)!=1?"s":"")i:=""
```

Notes:

1. Input from Clipboard
2. Output prints to any form by pressing <kbd>x</kbd>
3. Correctly handles plurals
4. Could be smaller but I wanted a provide a One Liner.

Answer (score 1):

## Go, <s>168</s> <s>132</s> <s>127</s> <s>120</s> <s>121</s> <s>120</s> 115 bytes

<s>[Try it here!](https://repl.it/B4nC/1)</s>

Even with minification, I'm <s>still [being beaten by Java ):](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5829/46231)</s> [finally beating Java!](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5829/46231)

*note: there's nothing in the spec about plurals nor excluding `0 minutes`, so my program ignores such cases.*

integer math in Go always returns an integer, thus this is straightforward.

```golang
package main
import(."fmt"."strconv")
func main(){a:=""
Scanln(&a)
x,_:=Atoi(a)
Printf((x/60),"hrs",(x%60),"mins")}
```

Ungolfed

```golang
package main

import (
    . "fmt"
    . "strconv"
)

func main() {
    a := ""
    Scanln(&a)
    x, _ := Atoi(a)
    Println((x / 60), "hrs", (x % 60), "mins")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arcyóu](https://github.com/nazek42/arcyou) (non-competitive), 93 bytes

*This submission uses a version of the language that was created after this challenge.*

```
(: x(#((v(l))0)))(: h(#/ x 60))(: m(% x 60))(% "%d hour%s %d minute%s"(' h(* s([ h))m(* s([ m
```

Yeesh! This language needs better string manipulation.

Explanation:

```
(: x              ; Set x
  (#              ; Cast to int
    ((v (l)) 0))) ; First element of input split on spaces
(: h (#/ x 60))   ; Set h to the hours
(: m (% x 60))    ; Set m to the minutes
(%                ; String format
  "%d hour%s %d minute%s"
  ('              ; List
    h             ; Hours
    (* s([ h))    ; Evaluates to 's' if h is not 1
    m             ; Minutes 
    (* s([ m      ; Evaluates to 's' is m is not 1
```

Answer (score 1):

### Kotlin, 132 bytes

```
val m={s:String->val j=s.split(" ")[0].toInt();print("${j/60} hour${if(j/60==1)"" else "s"} ${j%60} minute"+if(j%60==1)"" else "s")}
```

Ungolfed Version:

```
val m = { s: String -> 
    val j = s.split(" ")[0].toInt();
    print("${j / 60} hour${if(j / 60 == 1) "" else "s"} ${j % 60} minute" + if(j % 60 == 1) "" else "s")
}
```

Test it with:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    for(i in arrayOf(150, 90, 61, 60)) {
        m("$i min")
        println()
    }
}
```

Example outputs:

```
2 hours 30 minutes
1 hour 30 minutes
1 hour 1 minute
1 hour 0 minutes
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG.SE! I have edited your post to make is look more aesthetically pleasing. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

### Java 8, 148 Bytes

```
interface S{static void main(String[]b){int a=new Integer(b[0]),h=a/60,m=a%60;System.out.printf(h+" hour%s "+m+" minute%s",h>1?"s":"",m>1?"s":"");}}
```

I chose to post an alternative to @TheAustralianBirdEatingLouse as this is not only shorter by a good deal (~10%) but also more correct in printing hour(s) and minutes(s) instead of abbreviated hrs and mins. Method implementations in Interfaces are new to Java 8 - so this would be needed to compile/run

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <strike>110</strike> <strike>100</strike> 96 bytes

```
$t=$argv[1];$h=intval($t/60);$m=$t-$h*60;echo"$h hour".($h>1?"s":"")." $m minute".($m>1?"s":"");
```

You can run it using `php -r`

`GET` parameters are no longer allowed([meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7591/14732](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7591/14732) and [meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7575/14732](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7575/14732))

Comment: You can save bytes by just having `hour` and `minute` string and checking just for `s`.

Comment: @VasuAdari saved 10 bytes thanks to you.

Comment: You're welcome. One doubt, can you not do `$h,$m=1,2 or [1,2]` in php?

Comment: Unfortunately no. But I'm not aware if there's a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

### Java - <strike>143</strike> <strike>141</strike> 139 bytes

Since functions are allowed, here is my take

```
void a(String a){int b=Integer.valueOf(a.split(" ")[0]),c=b/60,d=b%60;System.out.print(c+" hour"+(c>1?"s ":" ")+d+" minute"+(d>1?"s":""));}
```

---

### Ungolfed

```
void a(String a){
    int b=Integer.valueOf(a.split(" ")[0]),c=b/60,d=b%60;
    System.out.print(
            c+" hour"+(c>1?"s ":" ")+
            d+" minute"+(d>1?"s":"")
            );
}
```

---

### Input

```
a("59 mins");
a("121 mins");
a("239 mins");
```

### Output

```
0 hour 59 minutes
2 hours 1 minute
3 hours 59 minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mumps, 81 Bytes

```
R U S M=+U#60,H=+U\60 W H," hour",$S(H=1:" ",1:"s "),M," minute",$S(M=1:"",1:"s")
```

Ungolfed:

```
R U                 ; (R)ead from standard input
S M=+U#60,H=+U\60   ; S(et) M to integer (mod) Minutes and H to integer Hours
W H," hour",$S(H=1:" ",1:"s "),M," minute",$S(M=1:"",1:"s")
                    ; W(rite) H & hour, if H doesn't equal 1 pluralize;
                    ; same for M & minute(s).
```

Sorry for the initial submission - the formatting on my ungolfed wasn't quite right and I didn't realize at first that hitting 'tab' then 'space' in the editor window equated to "submit." :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Prolog, 134 bytes

**Code:**

```
p(X):-sub_atom(X,0,_,4,S),atom_number(S,N),divmod(N,60,Q,R),(Q>1->I=s;I=""),(R=1->J="";J=s),writef('%w hour%w %w minute%w',[Q,I,R,J]).
```

**Explanation:**

```
p(X):-sub_atom(X,0,_,4,S),                       % Remove last 4 chars from input
      atom_number(S,N),                          % Convert to integer
      divmod(N,60,Q,R),                          % Split minutes into hours/minutes
      (Q>1->I=s;I=""),(R=1->J="";J=s),           % Check if hours/minutes are plural
      writef('%w hour%w %w minute%w',[Q,I,R,J]). % Print
```

**Example:**

```
p('150 min').
2 hours 30 minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 35 bytes

```
jds.b,N+WtNY\s.Ds-zG60c"hour minute
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?input=150%20min&test_suite_input=150%20min%0A90%20min%0A61%20min%0A60%20min&code=jds.b%2CN%2BWtNY%5Cs.Ds-zG60c%22hour%20minute&test_suite=0) or [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?input=150%20min&test_suite_input=150%20min%0A90%20min%0A61%20min%0A60%20min&code=jds.b%2CN%2BWtNY%5Cs.Ds-zG60c%22hour%20minute&test_suite=1)

#### Explanation:

```
jds.b,N+WtNY\s.Ds-zG60c"hour minute  implicit: z = input string
                 -zG                 remove all letters from the string
                s                    and convert it (gives us the number)
              .D    60               gives [quotient, remainder] (division by 60)
                      c"hour minute  split "hour minute"
   .b                                map each pair (number N, string Y) to:
     ,                                  the pair
      N                                 [ N, 
       +WtNY\s                               Y + "s" if N-1 ]
  s                                  join the two pairs
jd                                   join strings by spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

## awk, 72 bytes

```awk
{printf"%d hour%s %d minute%s\n",h=$1/60,h~/^1/?_:"s",m=$1%60,1~m?_:"s"}
```

Basically just a `printf`, taking advantage of awks ability to compare numbers using regexp.

#### input/output examples

```
0 min
0 hours 0 minutes
1 min
0 hours 1 minute
60 min
1 hour 0 minutes
61 min
1 hour 1 minute
121 min
2 hours 1 minute
122 min
2 hours 2 minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `Ṡ`, 29 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
OhN60ḋDð‘ƝḢ Ạẋ‘O+ZıẸs1>'s×+;Z
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#P2hlYWRlcj0mY29kZT1PaE42MCVFMSVCOCU4QkQlQzMlQjAlRTIlODAlOTglQzYlOUQlRTElQjglQTIlMjAlRTElQkElQTAlRTElQkElOEIlRTIlODAlOThPJTJCWiVDNCVCMSVFMSVCQSVCOHMxJTNFJ3MlQzMlOTclMkIlM0JaJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MTIxJTIwbWluJmZsYWdzPSVFMSVCOSVBMA==)

##### Explanation

```python
O          # Split on spaces
 hN        # Take the first item and convert to integer
   60ḋ     # Divmod by 60
      Dð   # Duplicate and push a space
‘ƝḢ Ạẋ‘    # Push compressed string "hour minute"
       O   # Split it on spaces
        +  # And prepend the space to each one
Z          # Zip it with the divmod list
 ı         # And map over this list of pairs:
  Ẹ        #  Dump onto the stack
   s       #  Swap so the number is on top
    1>     #  Is it greater than 1?
's        '#  Push the character "s"
  ×        #  Multiply by our boolean value
   +       #  Add to the string
    ;Z     # After the map, zip with the divmod list
           # Implicit output, joined by spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, <s>110</s> <s>99</s> 93 bytes

```julia
x->((h,m)=divrem(parse(x[1:end-4]),60);print("$h hour$(h>1?"s":"") $m minute$(m>1?"s":"")"))
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts a string and prints to STDOUT.

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(x::AbstractString)
    # Parse the number of minutes out of the input
    y = parse(x[1:end-4])

    # Get the number of hours and minutes
    h, m = divrem(y, 60)

    # Construct the output using string interpolation
    print("$h hour$(h>1?"s":"") $m minute$(m>1?"s":"")")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 175 bytes

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;main(int argc,char**argv){int a=stoi(argv[1]);cout<<a/60<<" hour";if(a/60!=1)cout<<"s";cout<<" "<<a%60<<" minute";if(a%60!=1)cout<<"s";}
```

Ungolfed:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int a = stoi(argv[1]);
   cout << a / 60 << " hour";
   if(a / 60 != 1) cout << "s";
   cout << " " << a % 60 << " minute";
   if(a % 60 != 1) cout << "s";
}
```

Probably the only time that `std::stoi` truncating non-number characters will ever be useful, but it's enough to put C++ ahead of C, I think.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by changing `!=1` to `>1`.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, <s>107</s> <s>192</s> <s>160</s> <s>149</s> <s>129</s> <s>172</s> <s>162</s> 129 bytes

So, here's my solution:

```
void b(String[]a){int a=Integer.valueOf(a[0]);System.out.print(a/60>1?a/60+" hrs ":a/60+" hr "+a%60>1?a%60+" mins":a%60+" min");}
```

It uses command-line input, and works like this:

Java command example: javac MovieTime 108 minutes

Input: `108 minutes`

Output: `1 hr 48 mins`

#### Changes:

- Changed the code to full class, adding 85 bytes
- Got rid of unnecessary whitespaces, subtracting 32 bytes
- Made variable/class names shorter, subtracting 11 bytes
- Made `Integer.valueOf(args[0])` into a variable and changed println into print, subtracting 20 bytes
- Added system for changing plurals of times, adding 43 bytes
- Made times shorter, subtracting 10 bytes
- Code is now a function instead of a class, subtracting 33 bytes

Any ideas as to how I can shorten it would be greatly appreciated, as this is my
 first golf submission.

Comment: Now get rid of all of that unnecessary whitespace around operators and braces.

Comment: And make the class name one character, and replace `String[] args` with `String[]a`.

Comment: You can also assign `Integer.valueOf(args[0])` to a variable.

Comment: @ThomasKwa wouldn't that increase the size due to declaration?

Comment: no; `int a=` and `;` takes 7 bytes, and you use it twice for a total of 9 bytes. `Integer.valueOf(args[0])` takes 26 bytes. Unless there's a shorter way to convert to int; I don't golf in Java.

Comment: You can also change println to print.

Comment: This doesn't use the singular/plural form of "hour(s)" and "minute(s)" depending on the number. Your test example should output `1 hour 48 minutes` (singular "hour").

Comment: @RetoKoradi Is that part necessary?

Comment: Absolutely. Handling that with as little code as possible is the most interesting part of this challenge. You can see that if you look at the other solutions.

Comment: I've added that in, so I believe I've got a final byte count of 162

Comment: You can make it a function, not necessarely a program...

Comment: @YassinHajaj Thank you, I did not realize that

Comment: Where does it say you can use `"hrs"` and `"mins"` instead of the actually specified `"hours"` and `"minutes"`?

Comment: If you can, then so shall I.

Comment: I don't think it matters, no one's told me anything and it does't specify in the OP you can't.

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 175 bytes

```
Sub e(f)
f = Val(f)
h = Int(f / 60)
m = f - h * 60
MsgBox IIf(h > 0, h & " hour" & IIf(h > 1, "s", ""), "") & " " & IIf(m > 0, m & " minute" & IIf(m > 1, "s", ""), "")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 102 bytes

```
a=int(raw_input().split()[0]);h=a/60;m=a%60;l="s\0";print"%s hour%s %s minute%s"%(h,l[h==1],m,l[m==1])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2: 56 bytes

#### Golfed code

```
m=int(raw_input()[:3]);print m/60,'hours',m%60,'minutes'
```

#### Readable code

```
# get input from STDIN
string_input = raw_input()
# parse number of minutes in the first three characters
minutes_input = string_input[:3]
# compute number of hours and remaining minutes
hours = minutes_input / 60
minutes = minutes_input % 60
# display result
print hours, 'hours', minutes, 'minutes'
```

#### Try it online

https://ideone.com/HdTKRt

---

## Python 2: 80 bytes (with plurals handling)

#### Golfed code

```
_,m='\0s',int(raw_input()[:3]);print m/60,'hour'+_[m>60],m%60,'minute'+_[m%60>1]
```

#### Try it online

https://ideone.com/GuDCq0

Comment: It should handle plurals.

Comment: @VasuAdari Now it does... although some answers around here don't.

Comment: I won't consider those answers :)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 96

```js
m=parseInt(prompt()),h=m/60|0,m%=60
alert(h+" hour"+(h!=1?"s ":" ")+m+" minute"+(m!=1?"s ":" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 41 bytes

```
A.Ds<4z60s[G" hour"?tG\skdH>4z"ute"?tH\s"
```

explanation

```
A                                          -Assign two values, first to `G` then to `H`
 .Ds   60                                  -DivMod on integer by 60
    <4z                                    -slice everything but the last 4 chars of input
         s[                                -print all following statements on one line
           G                               -hour
            " hour"                        -string literal
                   ?tG\sk                  -ternary, if hour is 1, 's' literal, else nothing
                         d                 -space
                          H                -minute
                           >4z             -get the last 4 chars of input (" min") (so sneaky)
                              "ute"        -string literal
                                   ?tH\s"  -ternary, as before but with minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Milky Way 1.2.1](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way), 63 bytes

```
'" "\=^A60m>?{1b_" "_"s "}" hour";+<?{1b_""_"s"}" minute";++++!
```

The program is too long to explain in detail here, but you can [see the docs](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way#milky-way) for an in-depth look.

---

#### Usage

```
python3 milkyway.py <path-to-code> -i <input>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Gema, 64 bytes

```
<N>=@p{@div{$1;60} hour} @p{@mod{$1;60} minute}
*=
p:1 *=$0;*=*s
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '<N>=@p{@div{$1;60} hour} @p{@mod{$1;60} minute};*=;p:1 *=$0;*=*s' <<< '90 min'
1 hour 30 minutes
```

### Gema, 65 bytes

```
<N> min=@p{@div{$1;60} hour} @p{@mod{$1;60} minute}
p:1 *=$0;*=*s
```

This one replaces all “\d+ min” occurrences in the input string.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '<N> min=@p{@div{$1;60} hour} @p{@mod{$1;60} minute};p:1 *=$0;*=*s' <<< $'150 min\n90 min\n61 min\n60 min'
2 hours 30 minutes
1 hour 30 minutes
1 hour 1 minute
1 hour 0 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, <s>95</s> 88 bytes

```
[ readln " " split first 10 >base [ 60 / floor ] [ 60 mod ] bi "%s hrs %s mins" printf ]
```

Like my Go answer, doesn't handle plurals because it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 31 bytes, noncompeting

```
dchE60.D]~U1 3:],FDJRh1N\s*+)_J
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=dchE60.D%5D%7EU1+3%3A%5D%2CFDJRh1N%5Cs%2a%2B%29_J&input=120+min)

Explanation:

```
dchE                            -     eval(input().split(" ")[0])
    60.D]                       -    [divmod(^, 60)]
               ],               -   zip(*[^,V])
         ~U1 3:                 -    ["minute", "hour"]
                 F          )   -  for _ in ^:
                     h1N        -     _[0] != 1
                        \s*     -    "s"*^
                           +    -    V+^
                   J            -     " ".join(_)
                             _J - " ".join(^[::-1])
```